# Mysql select distinct only if certain time difference exist

Tags: mysql, datetime, gaps-and-islands, group-by

I have a rather strange question.
I have a really big table which is the log of all the request made by everyone in my webservice.
This table has id, user_id, and a datetime field.
I now want to select distinct "sessions".
By session I mean that I consider requests that have more than 5 mins difference and the same user_id a different "session".
Is this possible without parsing programmatically each line ?

Comment: maybe you can add sample data :D

Comment: Look for gaps and islands. They are a lot of bibliography about this subject.

Comment: Hey found a sollution for this? trying to find something simular for gaps of 30 minutes to identify "sessions" of chats

Answer (score 1):

Round the datetime field to 5 min blocks (add/remove the minutes and seconds in the value) then select the distinct user_id and datetime rows.